# How to protect from spam with Sitecore Forms?

Tags: sitecore-forms

One of my clients is experiencing massive spam issues on their Sitecore 9.3 site which uses Sitecore Forms. On some forms we're seeing hundreds of spam submissions per minute!

The built-in robot detection can easily be bypassed (I won't disclose exactly how here) and spammers have seemed to notice this. We have contacted Sitecore Support and they suggested upgrading to Sitecore 10 which is not an option right now unfortunately.

Has anyone here faced similar spam issues and how can they best be resolved?

Comment: I will suggest you, go with Sitecore Forms extensions - https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions, it has a Robot Detection component and Google Recaptcha component which can be useful for your case.

Comment: Great suggestion. I've actually used the ReCaptcha field which does the job. Was wondering if there are different solutions though (ReCaptcha does affect conversion on forms)

Comment: I think as of now, ReCaptcha is the best solution.